# PHP dynamic variable

Tags: php, arrays, json, variables

I'm working in PHP.
I have a dynamic number of arrays called 'placeholder0, placeholder1, placeholder2....' and I want to json_encode them

```
$encode = json_encode(array('tabs' => $tabs, 'placeholder0' => $placeholder0, 'placeholder1' => $placeholder1, 'placeholder2' => $placeholder2 ..... ));
```

The number of values inside the 'tabs' array is the same as the number of 'placeholder' arrays.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array('tabs' => $tabs);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($tabs); $i++) {
    $result['placeholder' . $i] = ${'placeholder' . $i};
}

file_put_contents($jsonLocation, json_encode($result));
```

Comment: :)) sorry.. post it and I will delete mine :))

Comment: Nope this answer is great!

Comment: when I try `file_put_contents($jsonLocation, var_dump(json_encode($result)) );` it only comes up on the screean and doesn't get outputed in the file

Comment: I've updated the answer.. `var_dump` is just a debugging function which helps you to see the type and value of a variable..